# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, .net-4.6.1

I have a .NET Framework 4.6.1 project and need to reference a .NET 6 dll. I have no error adding the assembly except when executing the 4.6.1 client with the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"and need to reference a .NET 6 dll"_ - in short - you can't.

Comment: Is there any other possibility here? Using .NET standard? The client app is in .net 4.6.1.

Comment: Yes,  .NET standard is the way here.

Comment: Maybe I did not give enough details. I've no control over the .NET6 dll. It is from a third party. So, referencing this .NET6 dll in a .NETStandard project and then referencing this .NETStandard in a .NET framework 4.6.1, Should do the work?

Comment: No, it will not.

Comment: So, you stick your short answer, that I cant. :) In your opinion, what would be the right approach here, if upgrading the client app is not an option?

- Downgrade the 3rd Party dll.
- Memory Mapped files?

Other?

Comment: TBH have not done something like this but basically yes, you will need to create some decorator (if you don't want to ditch the client and write your own) app and use some kind of RPC.

Answer (score -1):

So based on what you said in the post, I'd assume you've manually added a .NET 6 DLL to your project. The error suggests that you might need to reference more DLLs to include all its required dependencies, e.g. .NET v6 version of `System.Runtime` etc.

Otherwise, try installing the .NET 6 SDK on your machine so that necessary runtime components/DLLs are available globally.

Also, something worth noting - the assembly binding redirects can potentially cause conflicts if it's not configured correctly. So check your configuration file and see if there's anything suspicious there.

Comment: Already did that. I've the SDK installed, no assembly redirect.